# Error while knitting an rmarkdown document - cannot find figure

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to manually knit an rmd document which calls a figure `fig1.gif`.

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'fig1.gif'.
<to be read again> 
               }
l.91 \includegraphics{fig1.gif}
```

The way I call the figure is:

```
![](fig1.gif)
```

The figure DOES exist in the directory.
Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: `pdflatex` and `xelatex` do not accept `gif` pictures - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file. The easiest way is probably to convert the gif to png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your code, but i can give you 2 hints:

1. Make sure that your file is next to your markdown file in the same directory.
2. Try `relative path`of the file.
3. Write a short snippet which checks if R can find your file.

I found a sample from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904983/how-do-i-check-the-existence-of-a-local-file).

```
        imgAddress="./ADDRESS bla bla/fig1.gif"     
         if (!file.exists(imgAddress)) {
            print("File is not found") }
         }
```

---

**I should cast doubt on the way which you load the image.** There are several packages which ,may help you:

```
library(magick)
tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 400)
print(tiger)
```

OR

```
earth <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/earth.gif") %>%
  image_scale("200x") %>%
  image_quantize(128)

length(earth)
```

Please read the below link. it will be usefull.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: I think the problem might be something else. It could be that the .gif is not a proper format, becuase when I run the same code with a .png it runs properly.

Comment: But, how does `![]` work? can you please explain it?

Comment: ---
 dev='cairo_pdf'
date: Sys.Date
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: no
    latex_engine: xelatex 
urlcolor: blue
---
```{r global_options, include=FALSE, dev='cairo_pdf' }
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'h')
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
```


```{r setup, include=FALSE, dev='cairo_pdf' }


```

![](fig1.jpg)

If you run this, you will get a pdf with the figure

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the effort. In the end it was the format of the figure that caused the bug...

Comment: I would generally recommend that you include graphics using the `includes_graphics` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856416/7347699